# javascript recursion and scope clarification

Tags: javascript, recursion

Doing a simple recursive function that calls another function and the scope is off to where it works the first time correctly but the next times it always **sets param to undefined**.

```
function log(string){
    console.log(string)
}

function repeat(operation, num, param) {
    if (num <= 0) return
    operation(param)
    return repeat(operation, --num)
}

repeat(log, 5, "hello there")
```

Comment: `par` ? normal it doesn't exist

Comment: What is "par"? That variable appears only once and is never declared or assigned a value. Anyway, the recursive call only passes two arguments, so...

Comment: Well, you're not passing any `param` argument during the recursive call, so yes, it will be undefined... try this `return repeat(operation, --num, param)`

Comment: yes this is correct, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the "param" parameter to the recursive calls.

```
function log(string){
    console.log(string)
}

function repeat(operation, num, param) {
    if (num <= 0) return
    operation(param)
    return repeat(operation, --num, param)
}

repeat(log, 5, "hello there")
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your variable name:

`par` => `param`

```
operation(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you just didn't want to do this?

```
function log(string) {
    console.log(string);
}

function repeat(operation, num, param) {
    if (num <= 0) return;
    operation(param);
    return repeat(operation, --num, param);
}

repeat(log, 5, "hello there")
```

Answer (score 1):

The working code is:

```
function log(string){
    console.log(string)
}

function repeat(operation, num, param) {
    if (num <= 0) return
    operation(param)
    return repeat(operation, --num, param)
}

repeat(log, 5, "hello there")
```

When you call the repeat recursively you should provide the 3rd argument - param

diff: return repeat(operation, --num, **param**)  on line 8